# Let CrudRepository use indexes of DB

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, indexing

I'm developing rest api service using spring boot, so i have the following table in db (postgres)

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name text,
  surname text,
  email text,
  password text,
  phone_code text,
  phone_number text,
  user_key text NOT NULL,
  registration_push_notification_id text,
  os_type text,
  bonuses integer,
  phone_number_verified boolean DEFAULT false,
  email_verified boolean DEFAULT false,
  active boolean DEFAULT false,
  car_mark text,
  car_body text,
  car_number text,
  settings jsonb,
  registration_time timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  blocked boolean DEFAULT false
}
```

And following interface `public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<Users,Integer>`

Now I add some indexes to db like

```
CREATE INDEX user_id
  ON users
  USING btree
  (id);
```

To test it i wrote simple rest controller with fooliwng structure

```
public String test(@PathVariable id){
        long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
        repository.findOne(id);
        long after = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time is: "+(after-before));
    }
```

The question is: before and after creation of index this method show the same result, in user table almost 100000 rows. Moreover this script

```
explain select * from users where id =4
```

show the following before index

```
"Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..12 rows=1 width=432)"
```

And after index

```
"Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..1.05 rows=1 width=432)"
```

How to check is spring boot use this index in method findOne(Integer in) ?

Comment: Spring Boot nor Spring Data JPa does anything with the indexes. In the end it is just a SQL query and your DB will decide if the query is used.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the complete execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`** (note the analyze option!). [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: try getting different rows and see if the plan changes. The rdbms may store these in order of id and sequential scan may be fastest for Id = 4. Spring, jdbc, and java have nothing to do with this